# Zend\Uuid why does exist in zend framwork2

Tags: zend-framework

I want to use `Zend\Uuid`  and I found [here](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=21266522)

But When I check the my local zend it doest exist this

How should I use this for my application ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not exist. The wiki page you linked to is a proposal for a component, and one that never made it into the framework.

Comment: So , Do you know how can I use it for my requirement?